# will_paginate dropping "sum" after first page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate which works like a charm for breaking up my results into many pages.  But on any page but the first one, my 'sum' method returns 0.

My view has two tables in it.  The first is summary information over the entire collection and the second is the paginated collection.  Page 1 of my collection shows everything perfect.  Page >= 2 turns the 'sum' to 0 yet .count still works.

My controller:

```
def donations_by_season
  @season_name = params[:season_name]
  @donations = Donation.by_season(@season_name).paginate :page=>params[:page], :order=>'created_at desc', :per_page => 25
  @valid_seasons = Donation.select(:season).group(:season)
end
```

My Partial has these values in the top table:

```
    <td> <%= number_to_currency @donations.sum(:amount) %></td>
    <td><%= @donations.count %></td>
```

And these in the lower:

```
<% @donations.each do |donation| %>
<tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even", :name => "row_class") %> ">
  <td><%= number_to_currency(donation.amount) %></td>
  <td><%= donation.iho_full %></td>
  <td><%= donation.box_code %></td>
  <td><%= donation.list_name %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<p><%= will_paginate @donations %></p>
```

On page one, `number_to_currency @donations.sum(:amount)` and `@donations.count` are accurate.  After page one, the .sum turns to 0 but the .count remains the same.  How do I get the .sum to work as well?

Comment: In @donations.count do you want to count the donations of all the pages of Donation.by_season or just count the donations of the selected page?

Comment: I wanted to count them all which it does just fine.  Basically the first table on the page is a summary of all donations for that season showing various bits of information including the total money that season and the total donations that season.  The second, paginated table shows the individual donations.  The issue I get is the total `@donations.sum` value goes to 0.  I find it odd that `@donations.count` does not, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe will_paginate is overriding the relation method "count".

If you take a look at the relation returned by the paginate method, it doesn't contain the elements that it says its counting.

The same for sum. It must be overwritting it, because it does not reflect what the true collection is returning.

If you refactor your code, to use:

```
@all_donations = Donation.by_season(@season_name)
@donations = @all_donations.paginate :page=>params[:page], :order=>'created_at desc', :per_page => 25
```

And use @all_donations, to get the count and sum metrics, it should work.

Comment: Thank you, Sir.  Such a simple solution, but for some reason my head wouldn't come up with it.  It works like I charm.  Sort of makes me feel like an idiot since I would have done that solution if working in any other language.  Still too new to ruby and rails.  Thank you, once again.

Comment: Don't worry about it, glad to help :). Just remember to select the answer  as correct by clicking the checkmark in the side of the question so people know that the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks again for the checkmark thing.  I never noticed that before.  I'll have to go back and check it for the other few questions I have had answered.  thanks!